# Scrapy does not export all lines scraped to csv file

Tags: python, web-crawler, scrapy

I am very new to Scrapy and also Python. I tried to scrape products of two specific brands from this whisky website https://www.masterofmalt.com/distilleries-and-brands/.

```
import scrapy


class WhiskyItem(scrapy.Item):
    name = scrapy.Field()
    country = scrapy.Field()
    region = scrapy.Field()
    distillery = scrapy.Field()

class WhiskySpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "whisky_stack"
    start_urls = ['https://www.masterofmalt.com/distilleries-and-brands/']

    def parse(self, response):
        brands = response.xpath("//nav[@class='distillery-and-brands-list']/ul/li/a/@href").extract()
        for brand in brands:
            if brand == "https://www.masterofmalt.com/distilleries/the-macallan-whisky-distillery/" \
            or brand == "https://www.masterofmalt.com/distilleries/glenfarclas-whisky-distillery/":
                yield scrapy.Request(brand, callback=self.parse_brands)

    def parse_brands(self, response):
        skus = response.css("div.product-box-wide").xpath("@data-product-url").extract()
        for sku in skus:
                yield scrapy.Request(sku, callback=self.parse_sku)
        pages = response.css("nav.list-paging-wrapper a::attr(href)").extract()
        if pages is not None:
            pages = list(set(pages))
            for page in pages:
                yield scrapy.Request(page, callback=self.parse_brands)

    def parse_sku(self, response):
        item = WhiskyItem() 
        item['name'] = response.xpath('//*[@id="ContentPlaceHolder1_pageH1"]/text()').extract()
        item['country'] = response.xpath('//*[@id="ContentPlaceHolder1_ctl00_ctl01_wdCountry"]/span[2]/a/text()').extract_first()
        item['region'] = response.xpath('//*[@id="ContentPlaceHolder1_ctl00_ctl01_wdRegion"]/span[2]/a/text()').extract_first()
        item['distillery'] = response.xpath('//*[@id="ContentPlaceHolder1_ctl00_ctl01_wdDistillery"]/span[2]/a/text()').extract_first()
        yield item
```

I can scrape all items from the website but the problem is that not all of them were exported to the csv file. Below is the command I use to export csv.

```
scrapy crawl whisky_stack -t csv -o whisky.csv
```

Is something going wrong here? Thanks!!!

Comment: I tested your script. And i scraped 532 items. May be you check output file and you see that order of items is different? That's fine, because scrapy sent requests asynchronously. And order of requests and exported items could be different. I started script 3 times, and each time it return same items count.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer!
I try to do this again and export the result to a csv file. After the task was done, The command box has the following message:

" [scrapy.extensions.feedexport] INFO: Stored csv feed (532 items) in: whisky.csv"

But only 340 lines are there in the csv file. So I suppose there should be something going wrong in the export process, but not the script itself?

The command I used to export csv file is -->
scrapy crawl whisky_stack -t csv -o whisky.csv